# Can I create index on a column with functions or analytical functions in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2016, analytic-functions

Can I create an Index on a column with functions or analytical functions?

I have a table `ABC` with columns XXX updateddatetime, YYY updatedusername. I am trying to create indices as shown below

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Cname1
ON ABC(UPPER(updatedusername));

CREATE INDEX idx_Cdate1
ON ABC(YEAR(updateddatetime));
```

I just get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '('

Is it possible to create index as shown above. Also, can I create an index on columns with analytical functions like LEAD, LAG, etc.,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can index a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017). That's different from trying to throw in an index on an expression that isn't a column.

Comment: You might [read about *indexed views*](https://aboutsqlserver.com/2011/03/24/indexed-materialized-views-in-microsoft-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Specify Computed Columns in a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017)

Create computed column

```
ALTER TABLE [t] ADD Cname1 AS ABC(UPPER(updatedusername))
ALTER TABLE [t] ADD Cdate1 AS ABC(YEAR(updateddatetime))
```

add PERSISTED no difference, the index still materializes the field

after create index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_Cname1
ON [T] (Cname1);

CREATE INDEX idx_Cdate1
ON [T] (Cdate1);
```